# Latest MongoDB installation

Tags: software-installation

Anyway tried to install the latest mongodb installation using the [ubuntu tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)? I tried it before but can't seem to replicate it. I'm getting this error when doing `sudo apt-get update`

> W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG D68FA50FEA312927 MongoDB 3.2 Release Signing Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is  **not** indicating that [the public key](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/error-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available) is missing but rather that the signature is bad.

I too  have same *warning* message,  I have tried all solutions provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors), but nothing works.

The possible workaround is Install from [tarball](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/):

*I am just copy & pasting commands here* from above link.

- Download the binary files for the desired release of MongoDB.

  ```
  curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.0.tgz
  ```
- Extract the files from the downloaded archive.

  ```
  tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.0.tgz
  ```
- Copy the extracted archive to the target directory.

  ```
  mkdir -p mongodb
  cp -R -n mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.2.0/ mongodb
  ```

**Note**:

**Don't just add keys from error messages. Only add keys you trust.** Because any repository with this key, would be able to install any package without warning.

*EDIT*:

mongodb 3.0 has no warning messages,

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: The given key was from mongodb official documentation so I trusted it. But still it gives the error message and Installing tarball is a bit lame.

Comment: yes, I too added key but still error persist.  Install from tarball is present alternative

Comment: @mateeyow please see my edit.

Comment: Yup, thanks! It seems to be an error on their end.

Comment: @Raven I've just submitted an issue regarding the GPG key and I think they fixed it already. Can't try it now because I need my documents but I'll be happy if you try it out yourself. :)